# I want to search premier inn by sending a postcode to the site

Tags: website, html

Hi I want to send a postcode from my site to premier inns and return the hotels in the area , does anyone know how I can go about it please ? if there is a method for finding a search string from a site can anybody share please

http://www.premierinn.com/en/homeQuickSearch!execute.action+ postcode ???

Any help would be great thanks

Mick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this particular site it is http://www.premierinn.com/en/homeQuickSearch!execute.action?searchModel.searchTerm=post+code&action=search

where post+code is the 2 part post code with + in the middle i.e. EC3M+5AD or N1+1AB